# Showing a piecewise function is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Given the following path defined on some topological space

$H(s,t) := \begin{cases}
f(s,t) , \space K(s) \leq L(t)\\
g(s,t) ,\space  K(s) \geq L(t)\\
\end{cases} $

I wish to prove that $H$ is continuous if $f,g,K,L$ are continuous such that $K(s) = L(t) \implies f(s,t) = g(s,t)$. And additionally we assume that for any fixed $s\in [0,1]$ that the set of solutions, $U\subset [0,1]$, to $ K(s) \leq L(t)$ is connected.

Any hints on how to show this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Where $\space f(s,t): [0,1]\times [0,1] \mapsto X$

$\space g(s,t): [0,1]\times [0,1] \mapsto X$

$\space K(s): [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$,
$\space L(t): [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm pretty sure $U \subset [0,1]^2$.

Comment: U is the set of all t satisfying $K(s) \leq L(t)$ for some fixed $s \in [0,1]$. So $U$ is a subset of [0,1].

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Vinicius. I know about this lemma, however I can't seem to apply it successfully to this situation.

Comment: Let $Q \in X$ be open.  Then $H^{-1}(Q) \in \{ f^{-1}(Q), g^{-1}(Q), P \subset f^{-1}(Q \cap [K(s) \leq L(t)]) \cup g^{-1}(Q \cap [K(s) \geq L(t)] \}$.  In the first two cases, the result follows from the continuity of $f$ and $g$.  The third case is all about the pasting lemma.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But what do you mean by $Q\cap [K(s) \leq L(t)]$?